# My installation failed and I need to get rid of the partition

Tags: system-installation

I can't find what partition it is though.

There's one labeled EFI system partition and its 260MB and theres another that's a recovery partition thats 845MB.

My installation started flashing weirdly so I shut it down and it doesn't give me the option to install alongside Windows.

Which is the partition I need to erase?

PS: I installed win2grub (whatever it's called) for some reason and I wanna get rid of that too.

Comment: Can you add the output of `lsblk`

Answer (score 1):

For cases like that, you should always have a flash drive with either [SystemRescueCd](https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) or [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) at hand. Both of these live distros offer nice graphical tools to fix all your partitioning and bootloader problems.